# I need a code to get emails of certain companies using freebase API in php

Tags: php, freebase

All i know is company name and its country. Can anyone provide a sample php code. On Running this code I get an error property not found, "organisation email contact".

```
<?php
  $service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search';
  $params = array(
    'query' => 'Emirates',
    'key' => "My-Key",
    'filter' => '(all type:/business/business_operation)',
    "output" => '(/organization/email_contact )',
//    "result" => array(
//      "/organization/organization/email" => [],
//      "name" => "Freebase Staff",
//      "id" => "/business/business_operation"
//    )
  );
  $url = $service_url . '?' . http_build_query($params);
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
  curl_close($ch);
  print "<pre>";print_r($response);print "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the output field parameter value:

> "output" => '(/organization/email_contact )' to "output" =>
>   '(all/organization/email_contact)'